# Odd Regex behaviour in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have made the following regex:

```
(?<=^PR)(?:[gpr])?([A-Z]{2,3})(?:vB)?(?=\d{4}$)
```

Which works in any regex testers. However when i try it in C# it acts a bit odd. Let's say i compare to it these 3 strings:

```
PRPCP2008, PRrSV2012 and PRBP2006
```

A regex tester matches the following:

```
PCP, SV and BP
```

This is what i want to happen. I only care about the 2 or 3 uppercase letters between "PR" and any 4 digit year. I do look for the lower case characters but don't want to match them. Now when i use the same regex in C# i get different matches:

```
PCP, rSV and BP
```

PCP and BP are still the same. But now it also includes the lowercase 'r'. Is there a reason why this happens in c#? Or did i just stumble upon a faulty regex tester?

If you'd like to test the regex, i used the following regex tester: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

EDIT:
Allright, the code

```
string regexPattern = @"(?<=^PR)(?:[gpr])?([A-Z]{2,3})(?:vB)?(?=\d{4}$)";

Regex regex = new Regex(regexPattern , RegexOptions.None);
Match match = regex.Match("PRrSV2012");

Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Comment: *i try it in C#* - how? Please post the code. Did you use a verbatim string literal to declare the regex?

Comment: I tried your pattern & string in the website you referenced. Returned 0 match. It's better if you can state the rule you want, in English, for us to help you

Comment: Note there are different regular expression engines that will execute certain regular expressions differently.  Make sure when testing that you use one that specificly has a C# or .Net option.

Comment: My bad. I meant that PRPCP2008 etc as single strings. Not all of them at once.

Comment: get this one `match.Groups[1]` instead of `match.Value`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Thank you, that gave the result i was looking for. But does that mean match.Value also includes non capture groups?

Comment: @Gnarly404 sorry. i would give answer if i knew the cause :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the match value, but you need a group.

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<=^PR)(?:[gpr])?(?'interest'[A-Z]{2,3})(?:vB)?(?=\d{4}$)", RegexOptions.None);

var items = new[] { "PRPCP2008", "PRrSV2012", "PRBP2006", "Foo"};

var results = items.Select(i => new { i, isMatch = rx.IsMatch(i), value = rx.Matches(i).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups["interest"].Value).FirstOrDefault()});
```

Result:

```
PRPCP2008 True PCP 
PRrSV2012 True SV 
PRBP2006 True BP 
Foo False null
```

That is the reason i always use explicitly named groups in my expressions.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you need to match multiple substrings with 1 regex. Then, you need to un-anchor the pattern (i.e. remove the `^` and `$`):

```
(?<=PR)(?:[gpr])?([A-Z]{2,3})(?:vB)?(?=\d{4})
```

In C#:

```
var reg = new Regex(@"(?<=PR)(?:[gpr])?([A-Z]{2,3})(?:vB)?(?=\d{4})");
var matches = reg.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Value).ToList();
```

Then, you will have your 3 matches.

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3dPR)(%3f%3a%5bgpr%5d)%3f(%5bA-Z%5d%7b2%2c3%7d)(%3f%3avB)%3f(%3f%3d%5cd%7b4%7d)&i=PRPCP2008%2c+PRrSV2012+and+PRBP2006)

[image]

**UPDATE**

You just need to use `.Groups[1].Value` to access the `SV` in `PRrSV2012`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5EPR)(%3F%3A%5Bgpr%5D)%3F(%5BA-Z%5D%7B2%2C3%7D)(%3F%3AvB)%3F(%3F%3D%5Cd%7B4%7D%24)&i=PRrSV2012).

```
string regexPattern = @"(?<=^PR)(?:[gpr])?([A-Z]{2,3})(?:vB)?(?=\d{4}$)";
Regex regex = new Regex(regexPattern , RegexOptions.None);
Match match = regex.Match("PRrSV2012");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
//                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/vYh0nu)

It is not stated directly in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx)  that a `Regex.Match` object includes capturing groups, but it is implied since `Match.Value` contains the whole matched text. Capture groups are part of it, thus, should be accessed after the match is found.

Comment: Why would it need to be case insensitive?